# In NetSuite's SuiteQL how can I get all related itemfulfillment ids from a salesorder in one record as csv?

Tags: netsuite, suiteql

I can get all item fulfillment ids but on multiple records using this query:

```
{
"q": "SELECT DISTINCT t.ID,t.TranID FROM NextTransactionLineLink AS ntll INNER JOIN Transaction AS t ON ( t.ID = ntll.NextDoc  ) WHERE t.type='ItemShip' AND  ( ntll.PreviousDoc = 7790 )"
```

}

Comment: Fix whatever consumes the result to accept multiple records in the format SuiteQL returns them in.

Comment: What I need is a function like the “FOR XML PATH”  in TSQL so I could get it natively from suiteql